# Streaming of video

Tags: video-streaming, streaming, system-design

As youtube streams, is separate copy of the video needed for each stream to a separate user? I meant that if the same video v1.mp4 is watched by 3 different users, will 3 separate copies of v1.mp4 be created and each streamed separately to 3 different users?

Comment: No, you don't need separate copies of the file to stream to multiple users.

Comment: Thanks Ken. So 3 separate streams will be created which will be connected to the same file.

Comment: Yes, that's right.